# The 'profile_pic' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner at django and python.

I build a model has ImageField.
The attribute of ImageField is Null=True and blank=True.

In my django app code, I try to access the ImageField like this.

```
maker['profileImg'] = item.user.profile_pic.url
```

But I got an error message.

So I modify the app code like this.

```
try:
    maker['profileImg'] = item.user.profile_pic.url
except:
    maker['profileImg'] = ''
```

is there any other good way?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `if` condition to check if there is an image or not in that particular field,

```
if item.user.profile_pic:
    maker['profileImg'] = item.user.profile_pic.url
else:
    maker['profileImg'] = ''
```

For one liner:

```
maker['profileImg'] = item.user.profile_pic.url if item.user.profile_pic else ''
```

Comment: is this shortest code? I like profileImg = item.user.profile_pic.url or '', It's not work in this case.

Comment: try the added one liner answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the `None` value, you could use this in one-line:

```
profileImg = item.user.profile_pic.url or ''
```

**EDIT**

Do not store `url`,  store `profile_pic` instead:

```
profileImg = item.user.profile_pic
```

And the when you need url:

```
if profileImg:
    print profileImg.url  # or whatever you need to di with url
```

Comment: The 'profile_pic' attribute has no file associated with it